# CSS spinner causing 2 get requests when js code is triggered

Tags: css

I am trying to create a loading spinner to put at the bottom of a div like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gr81twr/5/) so its always at the bottom when my returned code is appended to its sibling above its child element. Then when I scroll to the bottom of the page my endless scroll script runs and changes display from none to block of the spinner and once the next set of results is appended the spinner is hidden again.

The problem is is that once the scrollbar hits the bottom of the page the spinner triggers the get request twice for some reason and my results are doubled upon being appended. This happens only when the spinner div is inside the container element. My code runs fine with the spinner there appending the results once. Even using `position:relative;` on the container and `absolute` on the spinner div and setting `bottom:0px;` causes two get requests.

No matter how I create the spinners with CSS they all do the same thing multiple get requests. I have had to place the spinner in a div with `overflow:hidden;` also to prevent the jumping behavior of the scrollbar which causes continuous get requests when my code triggers.

Am I going the right way about this or is my logic flawed or what is wrong here?

**EDIT** js code that triggers the get request

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.pagination').length) {
    $('#id2').scroll(function() {
      var currentuserfeed = $('#currentuserfeed .pagination .next_page').attr('href');
      if (currentusershow && $('#id2')[0].scrollHeight > 820 && $('#id2').scrollTop () >= $('#id2')[0].scrollHeight - $('#id2').height ()) {
      return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: currentusershow, 
        data: { currentusershow: 'user' },
        dataType: 'script',
        });
      };
    });
    return $('#id2').scroll();
  };
};
```

Comment: From your description it seems to me that, the main problem lies in your request method. Somehow it's triggering twice. Can you please share the code your implementing to make the request?

Comment: I just added the js code. Now I think about it my code has attached twice on the scrolled element I just checked. I had this problem with my other scripts as I am using rails and was including the script in the view page with javascript_include_tag due to confusing `$(document).ready` with rails turbolinks. But you do not need it in rails scripts. Anyway I will check that.

Comment: Perhaps spinner div makes page height or `#id2` height bigger. So when you show spinner it makes possible to scroll a little bit to the bottom and trigger event one more time. Solution may be making spinner not adding to page height (i.e. `position: absolute;`). Or you may use js variable to check if loading event fired and not accept another loading event untill previous finishes.

Comment: I was thinking that too Sergiy at times but figured then that it is the attaching of the script twice. I have had some confusion with turbolinks and ajax calls and including scripts twice. Solution was to remove the javascript_include_tag and let asset pipeline load the script itself. Keep document.ready as its needed here.